# I can't start my ubuntu 12.10 after instalation

Tags: screen, hp

I use the HP Pavilion dm1 and have installed UBUNTU 12.10. But when I start my pc it will not start after appearing grub appears an orange screen and nothing else. So, I need to restart the pc in order to run ubuntu. I always need to restart your computer for it to run. what can I do?

Comment: I came across this peoblem too, but my ubuntu does not start whatever i do, it started once but i have run automatic updates then never again ...

Answer (score 0):

I'll love to know these: Is the ubuntu OS working, as in booting for you to use? Do you mean for the first time when you switch your pc on (cold booting) it doesn't work, but only works after second and subsequent restarting?